# CMake idiom regarding minimum microarchitecture checking

Tags: c++, cmake, idioms, compute-capability

Suppose I have a CUDA project and I'm writing its `CMakeLists.txt`.

In my project, I have several `.cu` source files with kernels, each of which has a minimum NVIDIA microarchitecture version it supports.

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I would like to be able to...

- Detect, or at least be able to specify, this minimum uarch of each file (not the set of uarchitectures to build for - a minimum for which the target *may* be built).
- (perhaps) Compute and print the intersection of these acceptable ranges of compute capabuilties (since I've only talked about minimum - it's the maximum of the minima).
- Have CMake configuration *fail* if there are no GPUs on the system supporting a uarch in the intersection (... unless this is a cross-build, in which case the user has specified the target architecture/s  and the build system GPUs are irrelevant).
- Be able to specify which GPU I'm targetting, so that only its CC is checked against the range of acceptable uarches/CC values.

I don't really see any of that when looking at the documentation, e.g. at the [`CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html) and [`CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html) pages.

Comment: This is strange requirement: `fail if there are no GPUs on the system supporting a uarch in the intersection.` - example where this requirement doesn't make sense: build application in continues integration system which do not have required hardware, but then for tests. Having to restrictive build system is bad thing.

Comment: @MarekR: That would be an example of a cross-build. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: do it outside of CMake. use a shell script, python program, etc. run it via CMake's `execute_process()` and act on its results.

Comment: @nega: But CMake should support this itself - it's one of, if not the, most common scenario when building GPU-targeting CUDA code. Of course I can always do things instead of CMake by programming them myself and running execute_process()...

Comment: to detect your minimum uarch you'll have to "shell out", or slurp the files into cmake strings, and do a substring/regex search. to specify your min uarch use source _file properties_ (`COMPILE_*`) to set the relevant compiler flags. you'll have to roll your own function/macro to compute the intersection of cmake lists (or google for one, or ask a separate question here, etc). to detect capabilities of installed GPU's you'll have to "shell out".  to specify the GPU you're targeting, use  _target properties_ to set the relevant compiler/linker flags.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, CMake does not support this. I have filed a [bug with Kitware](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25105) for adding such support via a source file property and some set arithmetic during configuration time.